# Which version of Miniconda has Python 3.6 for Windows 64-bit?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, miniconda

I'm working on a project which need these deep learning libraries - keras and tensorflow. Unfortunately, these do not work with Python 3.7. Can someone please tell me a Miniconda version (for Windows 64-bit) which has Python 3.6?
I've tried creating virtual environment with Python 3.6, but the libraries don't install properly.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I wanted to find the last package in the 3.6 series, so I found the [announcement of the python 3.7 package build](https://www.anaconda.com/python-3-7-package-build-out-miniconda-release/) (September 4, 2018) and then looked that package up by date in https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/ (Miniconda3-4.5.11), then traced it back one release. The end result:

Miniconda3-4.5.4 was the last Python 3.6 miniconda package.

Miniconda3-4.5.11 is the first that uses 3.7.

There are no releases 4.5.5->4.5.10 in that repository.

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat awkward way of doing it. Is there not a description filed for packages which tells which version of python it comes with? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just downloaded Miniconda3-4.3.31 for Windows 64bit and it came with Python 3.6.3.

https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/
Binary: https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.31-Windows-x86_64.exe