# Which installer to use for Miniconda with Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, miniconda

I’ve planned to use Miniconda (MC) and TensirFlow (TF) together, and since TF with Python 3 [requires](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6, I need to install an older version of MC with Python 3.

However, the installer naming convention on the [archive page](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/) is a bit unclear. What I want is Python 3.6 x64 for Windows, but for this there seems to be two installers: `Miniconda-3.6.0-Windows-x86_64.exe` and `Miniconda3-3.6.0-Windows-x86_64.exe`. What’s the difference between these?

Also, while both of these intuitively seem to indicate Python 3.6, what’s up with other installers such as `Miniconda3-4.5.12-Windows-x86_64.exe`; for sure, this cannot indicator Python 4.5? What is going on here?

Comment: Who says, that the `3.6.0` has something to do with the python version ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628161/which-version-of-miniconda-has-python-3-6-for-windows-64-bit))? Yes, it's might be hard to find a list mapping miniconda versions to python versions (somewhat within [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/)). But the reason is probably simple: you should always install the `latest` and if you need to downgrade python, create a fresh environment (within your newly conda) using python 3.6.

Comment: The version 4.5.12 indicates the version of the MiniConda build. Similarly 3.6.0 also indicate the same. MiniConda3 means that it can create enviroments in Python 3.x versions.

Comment: Ah, then it makes more sense. Thanks, both of you!

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal So if I would install `Miniconda-3.6.0-Windows-x86_64.exe` (for example), wouldn't it be able to create virtual environments? What Python version _does_ this installed ship with, by the way? None?

Answer (score 6):

Find older version of conda from here: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/

https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh is python 3.6.0

Answer (score 2):

Stick with the miniconda `latest`, so in your case `Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe`.  Unlike pip, Conda is a very intelligent package manager and will try to match dependency versions so that your installed packages will all work in a given virtual environment.  My suggestion is to create a conda virtual environment, and then install TensorFlow inside.  This is what I do at work.

Also, FYI, the conda version of TensorFlow has been optimized to run faster than the pip version in many situations [see this post from Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/tensorflow-in-anaconda/).

Example:

```
    conda create -n tf
    conda activate tf
    conda install tensorflow
    ## alternatively if you have a compatible nvidia gpu:
    conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: The TensorFlow version I want to install, `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0`, is "not available from current channels" according to conda. Can I still use a conda virtual environment for TF, even though I have to install TF with `pip` (i.e. will TF be limited to that environment only)?

Comment: Yes, you can install pip packages into conda virtual environments!  When you initially setup up your virtual environment, just run `conda create -n tf python=3.6`, otherwise, I believe the default python in conda is 3.7 now.

Comment: When I install `PySide2` with `pip` from within the environment, `python` isn't able to find the package, even though I see it when I do `pip list`. Do you know what's the problem here?

Comment: (I eventually went with TF1 anyway, since the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#2.-create-a-virtual-environment-recommended) prompts you to install the TF pip package using its complete URL, and there is no URL for TF2 for Windows)

Comment: According to [this page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment), it seems that one needs to add the argument `pip` when creating a new environment in which pip is going to be used. They also do that on the [TF installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#2.-create-a-virtual-environment-recommended). I had missed that, and when using `conda create -n tf pip python=3.6` instead, `python` was able to find PySide2 (after having reinstalled all manually added packages).

Comment: Adding to the helpful comments by @HelloGoodbye : it is now sufficient to create a new environment with 'conda create -n tf python'. This includes the installation of pip. You can verify this by 'which pip' showing a path to the pip version within the newly created conda env.

Comment: @AgileBean I've also realized that is how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can’t speak for windows.  I think within the virtual environment, you’ll also have to install pip, so `conda install pip`

Comment: No, `pip` is already available. I guess MiniConda makes sure that pip is available in the environment if you’re using Python 2.7.9 (or greater) or Python 3.4 (or greater), since those Python versions [ship with pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) when installing CPython, and I suspect MiniConda tries to mimic that behavior.